# Responsive Platforms - Grid or Gridless?

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

I wanted to get opinions on Responsive Design approach, both for designers and developers.  My experience has been thus far using a gridless approach, where media queries change DOM elements at the needed breakpoints.  This has allowed me to be very nimble for accommodating design specifications.  Sometimes I get a "grid" design that just doesn't break down to the right number of columns and that would screw up using a standard grid system like bootstrap (though I realize you can easily customize bootstrap to a certain degree).  For example, I once received a design having layouts for 10, 8, 5, and 2 columns.

My concerns are that I'm perhaps:

- Making the whole implementation harder than it is.
- Ending up with complicated, fragile (and sometimes spaghetti) CSS.
- Making future development more difficult.

I'd appreciate any opinions regarding pros and cons on using a Responsive grid or going custom gridless.  Do we need to keep the designers on their toes and QA the design as per platform?  Is there more flexibility to grids that there seems to be?

I'd prefer to start using either Foundation of Bootstrap, but any recommendations are welcome.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last year we started to use Twitter Bootstrap http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/ and it became an excelent way to guide the responsive design on our web application.

Take a look and check the benefits that you can get. For us, the most benefits were:
- Cross-browser & Responsive (of course);
- Guide with great documentation to developers (that probably was the greater);
- Ease and simplicity;

Answer (score 0):

If you're all about developing your code more from scratch than utlizing some pre-build foundation then I first suggest a look at [XY CSS](http://xycss.com).  XY CSS allows you the versatility of defining however many grid columns you want.  You could design with 36 grids in mind for example, which would potentially allow you to contain 36 individual columns across the width of your screen.

Another option would be to use a pre-build but relatively easy framework to modify, which I would suggest [Columnal](http://www.columnal.com/).  I like Columnal as the CSS inside is well written and it is not overly complex while also not being too simplistic to be limited in functionality.  It's also very easy to modify.

I would suggest against Bootstrap because firstly, I am not a bootstrap fanboy, and secondly, I find it rather "bloated".  By bloated I mean it provides you with a lot of crap that you don't necessarily need, or stuff that you want, but you would rather use a different system that is faster, or more well documented, or any numerous other reasons.  My primary beef with bootstrap is that it was originally made for Twitter, and then they said hey let's give it to everyone else and they modified the shit out of it and now it's this unkind beast of thing where you almost have to use what they give you because if you don't the system punishes you at every turn for trying to change anything.  I prefer to stick to systems that were originally intended for use by the likes of people like you and I.  For that same reason, I would suggest foundation or bootstrap.

This is my personal opinion and should not be construed as anything but my opinion.